# Clear route data from Url.RouteUrl

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, attributerouting

In a view, if I use

```
@Url.RouteUrl(MVC.Home.Actions.Foo())
```

where `MVC.Home.Actions.Foo()` is an `ActionResult` generated by T4MVC,

then I expect to get `/foo` (which is what I've defined via attribute routing)

but I actually get `/foo?RouteValueDictionary=System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary`

*How do I get the url that I want?*

Incidentally, the action is as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("foo")]
public virtual ActionResult Foo(string bar) { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: Could you show your action declaration (`MVC.Home.Actions.Foo()`) with AttributeRouting decoration?

Comment: @plentysmart I've edited the question accordingly

Comment: `@Url.RouteUrl("foo")` should be sufficient

Comment: @StephenMuecke That gives me "A route named 'foo' could not be found in the route collection"

Comment: I've decided to use `@Url.Action(MVC.Home.Actions.Foo())` which gives me the desired result. But my original question still holds, not sure how to solve it.

Comment: @hbob, Sorry, you would need to add the `RouteName = "foo"` to the attribute

Comment: @StephenMuecke Nope that just returns "/?...etc." which is worse than before. It seems `Route("foo")` works though.